# Emscripten package on Ubuntu 16.04. How to get it to work?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, emscripten

I installed Emscripten on Ubuntu 16.04, using the command:

apt-get install emscripten

It seemed to work, but I am unable to compile a simple hello world example, because I get:

/usr/bin/lli: error creating EE: No available targets are compatible with this triple, see -version for the available targets.

Why does it happen? Is there a way to fix it? I tried to google for it, finding only useless information: most forum suggested to use a more recent version (the version included in Ubuntu 16 is the 1.22), but I would prefer to use the version provided with the OS (even if old, it should be supposed to work, and I am not interested in the new features). Other forums suggested to use portable emsdk. I am not interested in using it, either, since I have a 32 bit installation and the precompiled package on the official site is 64 bit only.

What I am interested in is to find how to configure the version of emscripten provided with Ubuntu (or, if this is not possible at all, to know why, since official packages of the OS are supposed to work out of the box, usually). I put the above disclaimer to avoid getting just the answers already published in other forums: I am aware of the existence of a newer version, and I have my reasons for not using it.

Thank you in advance, and... any idea?

Comment: I also tried emscripten from apt and it didn't work. If they don't have 32 bit binaries you can try [building emscripten from source](https://emscripten.org/docs/building_from_source/index.html#installing-from-source).

Comment: I filed a bug report, would you like to state that affects you too? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emscripten/+bug/1892784

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the emscripten package is not set up properly. In general the emscripten developers recommend downloading the emsdk directly,

https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html

That version is constantly tested and guaranteed to work, and it's easy to install. (Distro versions may work, but even if they do they tend to be older than the current emsdk release.)

Comment: Ubuntu is perhaps the most well known distro of Linux, so it's hard to believe that they put a faulty version. As I stated, I was aware of the option to download the emsdk directly, but I would rather not to use it since it requires the 64 bit version and I have the 32 bit version.